# pb for build an HTML table with table PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I try to make a table html, with 2 table PHP,
I don't manage to put my value which is in my 4th row, 3th column in the 4th row, 4th column.

[image]

My PHP/html:

```
<table BORDER=1px>
<tr>
<?php
foreach($tableau1 as $value)
{
    echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
}
?>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($tableau as $valu)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($tableau1 as $val => $ke)
    {
        foreach($valu as $vava => $keke)
        {
            if($val==$vava){echo '<td>'.$keke.'</td>';}
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

My PHP table (first:table , second:table1)

```
array (size=3)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'marque' => string 'marque 6' (length=8)
      'modele' => string 'modele 6' (length=8)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'marque' => string 'marque 3' (length=8)
      'modele' => string 'modele 3' (length=8)
      2 => string 'bois art3' (length=9)
      4 => string 'beton art3' (length=10)
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'marque' => string '-lepetit' (length=8)
      'modele' => string 'modele 5' (length=8)
      4 => string 'beton art5' (length=10)
array (size=4)
  'marque' => string 'marque' (length=6)
  'modele' => string 'modèle' (length=6)
  2 => string 'bois' (length=4)
  4 => string 'beton' (length=5)
```

Response to first answer:
:) I already tried it but it's not good I get too much cell in all row and I don't understand why ...

[image]

Comment: Try the code now.  I moved the empty '<td></td>' outside of the inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to print an empty `<td></td>` when no data for the cell.

```
<?php
foreach($tableau as $valu)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($tableau1 as $val => $ke)
    {
        $found = false;
        foreach($valu as $vava => $keke)
        {
            //echo '<td>' . $val . ' ' . $vava . ' ' . $keke . '</td>';
            if($val==$vava){ 
                echo '<td>'.$keke.'</td>';
                $found = true;
            } 

        }
        if (!$found) { echo '<td></td>'; }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Added a boolean to flag when data was added to the column and then moved the

```
echo '<td></td>';
```

outside of the inner loop.